# How to use recursive_directory_iterator with algorithm library and std::remove_if in particular?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, c++17

I want to filter out some entries from the recursive directory listing using the standard algorithms. Let say leave only regular files. 
Some algorithms from STL do work, e.g. `std::count_if`, but others, e.g `std::remove_if`, do not.

<del>Should it work or is the `recursive_directory_iterator` intentionally not (fully) compatible with STL?</del>

Given `recursive_directory_iterator` is there a way to proceed regular files only in a functional-programming style (and possible chain other filters afterwards)?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
  { // count_if is fine
    auto dir_listing = fs::recursive_directory_iterator("/tmp/myfiles");
    auto n = std::count_if(begin(dir_listing), end(dir_listing), [](auto &p) { return fs::is_regular_file(p); });
    std::cout << n << '\n';
  }

  { // remove_if does not even compile
    auto dir_listing = fs::recursive_directory_iterator("/tmp/myfiles");
    auto my_files = std::remove_if(begin(dir_listing), end(dir_listing), [](const fs::path &p) { return !fs::is_regular_file(p); });
    for (auto &f : my_files)
    {
      std::cout << f << '\n';
    }
  }
}
```

Compiling with gcc-7 leads to an error (clang-5 as well)

```
g++-7 myfiles.cpp -std=c++1z -lstdc++fs
...
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:871:16: error: passing ‘const std::experimental::filesystem::v1::directory_entry’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
      *__result = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__first);
```

And after adding `-fpermissive` it just segfaults.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `remove_if` to do here?

Comment: given `recursive_directory_iterator` is there a way to proceed regular files only in a _functional-programming_ style (and possible chain other filters afterwards)?

Comment: Not easily possible with just standard iterators. Have a look at [boost range library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) which allows for chaining.

Comment: Or Eric Niebler's range-v3 library: https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3

Comment: Also http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::remove_if` expects forward iterators, pointing to move assignable values. `recursive_directory_iterator` is an input iterator, and the values it points to are const (so not move assignable).

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but `std::remove/remove_if` is for removing items from a collection. Not all iterators point into collections, as is the case with `recursive_directory_iterator`.

If you're trying to use it as a filter that you want to possibly forward to other algorithms, unfortunately the standard library does not have direct support for that. The best you can probably do (with the standard library) is use `remove_copy_if` with `back_inserter` to filter elements into a vector, and then do further processing on that vector.

```
std::vector<fs::path> paths;
std::remove_copy_if(begin(dir_listing), end(dir_listing), std::back_inserter(paths),
    [](const fs::path& p) {
        return !fs::is_regular_file(p);
    });
```

Comment: Just what I was about to write. ;-) @sciamano It helps to look at the [iterator categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Iterator_categories). If a function expects a certain category, you can only pass it an iterator of the same or a less restrictive category (those on the left side of the expected category). Also the use of `begin(dir_listing)` and `end(dir_listing)` implies a misunderstanding of `recursive_directory_iterator`. It is not a collection like a `std::vector`.

Comment: @zett42: It's not a collection, but it nevertheless supports `begin` and `end`. `begin` returns the iterator itself, and `end` returns a default constructed iterator. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/begin

Comment: Interesting although it feels somewhat strange. It's propably there for convenience only as ranges have not made it into the standard yet.

Comment: @zett42: Yes, it's there mainly so you can pass it to a range-based for loop.